# Nested json_agg

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this postgresql query, which returns a json containing all books titles, the first and lastname of their authors and an array of all reviews titles + the first and lastname of the reviewer.

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'title', a.title,
    'author_firstname', b.firstname,
    'author_lastname', b.lastname,
    'reviews', json_agg(json_build_object(
        'review_title', c.title,
        'reviewer_firstname', d.firstname,
        'reviewer_lastname', d.lastname
    ))
)
FROM book AS a
INNER JOIN person AS b ON a.author_id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN review AS c ON c.book_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN person AS d ON c.reviewer_id = d.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

This works and is quite fast. I need to extend this query to include all the titles of the books of the reviewers too.

I followed the logic I used for the first left join

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'title', a.title,
    'author_firstname', b.firstname,
    'author_lastname', b.lastname,
    'reviews', json_agg(json_build_object(
        'review_title', c.title,
        'reviewer_firstname', d.firstname,
        'reviewer_lastname', d.lastname,
        'reviewer_books', json_agg(json_build_object(
            'book_title', e.title
        ))
    ))
)
FROM book AS a
INNER JOIN person AS b ON a.author_id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN review AS c ON c.book_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN person AS d ON c.reviewer_id = d.id
        LEFT JOIN book AS e ON e.author_id = d.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

But this does not work because `aggregate function calls cannot be nested`. Is there a solution to this, which can be extended to include even deeper relations (like all the reviews of all the books of the reviewer) and is relatively efficient.

Those databases are confusing me, so thank you for your help!

Comment: The use of arbitrary letters as table aliases is a really bad practice.  You should use abbreviations for table names, such as `b` for `book` and `p` for `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple levels of aggregation.  This is something like:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'title', b.title,
    'author_firstname', p.firstname,
    'author_lastname', p.lastname,
    r.reviews
)
FROM book b INNER JOIN
     person p
     ON b.author_id = pb.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.book_id,
             json_agg(json_build_object('review_title', r.title,
                                        'reviewer_firstname', pr.firstname,
                                        'reviewer_lastname', pr.lastname,
                                        'reviewer_books', rb.reviewer_books
                                       )
                     ) as reviews
      FROM review r JOIN
           person pr
           on r.reviewer_id = pr.id JOIN
           (SELECT r2.reviewer_id, json_agg(json_build_object('book_title', b2.title) as reviewer_books
            FROM reviews r2 JOIN
                 book b2
                 ON r2.book_id = b2.id
            GROUP BY r2.reviewer_id
           ) rb
           on r.reviewer_id = rb.reviewer_id
    ) r
    on r.book_id = b.id;
```